# Date array element to PHP array variable

Tags: php, arrays, date

I had datepicker element in HTML code ( multiple datepicker ) from for loop (data from database)

It display fine and let user choose different dates for different product.
on submit, assign these dates into php variable through post.

But the element remains string not dates.
How to change string to date in php?

```
<td colspan=2>
    <input type="text" 
           name="expirydate[]" 
           id="expirydate<? echo $SNO;?>" 
           autocomplete="off"  
           class="expirydate" 
           value="<? $DateToday=date('Y-m-d');
                     $ShowDate1 = explode("-", $DateToday);
                     $ShowDate2 = "$ShowDate1[2]/$ShowDate1[1]/$ShowDate1[0]";
                     echo $ShowDate2; ?>"
    />
</td>
```

```
$(function(){
        $('.expirydate').datepicker({ minDate: 0 }); 
});
```

```
$expirydate = $_POST["expirydate"];

for ($x=0; $x<=$TotalCount-1; $x++)
    {
    $expirydate1 = $expirydate[$x];
    $n1 = explode("/", $expirydate1);
    echo $n1[0] . "--" . $n1[1] . "--" . $n1[2] . "<br>";
    $n2 = "$n1[2]-$n1[1]-$n1[0]";
    $n22 = date_create($n2);
    $n3 = date_format($n22,"Y/m/d H:i:s");
}
```

Comment: **<?** is not **PHP open tag**. **<?php** is.

Comment: ok fine. but it is working.

Comment: Please post the value of `$expirydate`

Comment: $expirydate is an array and it gives dates as string....27/11/2019,28/11/2019,29/11/2019 likewise

Answer (score 1):

According your code above `$ShowDate2` is in the format of `d/m/Y`.
Using [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) you can parse the date string into a [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '27/11/2019');
```

If you want it formatted just use the format method on it: `$date->format('Y-m-d')`.

If your `$expirydate` is an array of dates in the mentioned `d/m/Y` format, you can do the following:

```
$expirydate = [ '27/11/2019', '26/11/2019', '25/11/2019'];
$dates = array_map(function($date) {
    return DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
}, $expirydate);
```

Comment: $expirydate is an array but of string type. it takes dates as string

Comment: @himanshoo then you can use the snippet above in order to parse the date strings into datetime object, the resulting `$dates` is an array of datetime objects.